# doctrine2 shared where - equivalent of custom filterby from propel

Tags: doctrine-orm, propel

Is it possible?

Currently I'm using something like that:

```
class ReportRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getActiveReportsQuery() 
    {
        return $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('report')
            ->from('ClearcodeTransparenBundle:Report', 'report')
            ->where('report.status = :status')
            ->setParameter('status', Report::STATUS_OPEN)
        ;
    }
}
```

But I cant the use this construct with count.

So, is there a direct equivalent of  filterbyIsSomething from propel1?